# MX record issue for Godaddy hosted emails on Amazon route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, mx-record

We were using ey3 hosting (Godaddy reseller) for hosting application and emails. Recently we decided to move our application hosting to Amazon and for that we decided to use Amazon Route 53 services as well. We were successfully able to switch the name servers and then the application started working perfectly from new server.

However we decided to keep using our existing email hosting on ey3 (Godaddy reseller) and for that we updated MX records on Amazon however its not working fine. Its been nearly three days since we are struggling to fix this.

Here are MX record which I have setup on Amazon route 53

```
example.com MX 0 smtp.secureserver.net
example.com MX 10 mailstore1.secureserver.net
```

When we try to send email on test@example.com from Gmail/Yahoo/hotmail etc. we are getting

> SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO::
>       host smtp.secureserver.net [72.167.238.29]: 550 5.1.1  recipient rejected

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Also while I was making some changes 2 days back the mails started working fine before it again stopped all of sudden. So I am sure there is something wrong in the MX records

Comment: Please clarify the context of the error... can you not send mail, or not receive mail?  (What happens if you send yourself a message from a gmail account?)

Comment: @sqlbot We are able to send mails from the webmail which is provided by Godaddy however when I try to send mails to email accounts hosted on our domain from third party email services e.g. Gmail/Yahoo/hotmail etc. I get the above error.

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

While I did not directly have specified anywhere the use of an SMTP server, just last week (Feb 2019) I connected my GoDaddy website to Amazon S3, with the Nameservers being routed through Route53, and the emails operating with Gmail.

To get the email to operate through Route53 I entered the following settings in a new record set,

```
Name   | blank  @domain.com.au 
Type   | mx
values | 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
         5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
         5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
         10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
         10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
TTL    | 3800
```

To create an alias email address which routes emails to my working email address the following details were included in a new record set,

```
Name  | new@mydomain.com.au
Type  | ptr
Value | original@mydomain.com.au
```